# How to get 3v3 pins on Arduino Mega Sensor shield v2.0?

Tags: arduino-mega, sensors

I am using Arduino mega and a sensor shield (picture attached below). I need to connect three different wires to 3.3 V input. Can anybody suggest how can I achieve the same? What voltage do the VCC pins of all digital and analog pins on the sensor shield have?

[image]

Comment: Is there a pin marked with 3.3 or similar? If not, you will need an external voltage regulator. If yes, you should make sure, that is can provide enough current for the sensors

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They are all 5V as the Mega2560 uses 5 V logic.  However, there is a `3V3` pin at the bottom, second pin from the left, that you could use:

[image: Mega sensor shield]

However, unfortunately, the pin isn't protruding *above the shield*, so you'll have to make an ugly solder link to the top of the pin. Either that, or remove the row of pins and replace with a female header (carefully avoiding the `SD card` pins):

[image: Female header pins]

---

As an aside, the [Iteaduino MEGA 2560](https://www.itead.cc/wiki/Iteaduino_MEGA_2560) works at 3V3 but unfortunately the Mega shield that you have won't fit it.

[image: Iteaduino MEGA 2560]

The Uno equivalent of your shield will fit it though:

[image: Uno sensor shield]

Comment: I guess the shield would still provide 5 V from the 5 V pin of the 3.3 V Mega

Answer (score -1):

I fix it solding into the board sensor shield the point where there is the pin 3.3v

[image]